# RPM processes running wild

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux

for some reason there are 40+ rpm processes running under root and are taking 100% of all 32 CPU's on a server. has someone encountered this before? running on RHEL 6.1.. I'm just curious if anyone has seen this or something similar, there are 7 other boxes with the exact same configuration, but that's the only one with issues.

```
16491 root      20   0 70648 3172 2520 R 22.4  0.0   4113:38 rpm
30976 root      20   0 70648 3164 2512 R 22.4  0.0   1870:30 rpm
 2509 root      20   0  163m 3268 2620 R 20.8  0.0   6506:13 rpm
11534 root      20   0 70648 3164 2516 R 20.8  0.0   1271:55 rpm
17443 root      20   0 70648 3168 2520 R 20.8  0.0   5329:28 rpm
18041 root      20   0 70648 3160 2512 R 20.8  0.0   3710:12 rpm
24687 root      20   0 70648 3168 2520 R 20.8  0.0   2255:58 rpm
30295 root      20   0 70648 3160 2512 R 20.8  0.0 658:31.04 rpm
  415 root      20   0 70648 3164 2516 R 19.2  0.0   2612:31 rpm
 1772 root      20   0 70648 3160 2512 R 19.2  0.0  15973:06 rpm
 2714 root      20   0 70648 3164 2516 R 19.2  0.0  15760:34 rpm
 3022 root      20   0 70648 3160 2512 R 19.2  0.0   9138:11 rpm
 3694 root      20   0 70648 3164 2516 R 19.2  0.0   9075:03 rpm
 6114 root      20   0 70648 2744 2096 R 19.2  0.0  20164:31 rpm
 7162 root      20   0 70648 3164 2516 R 19.2  0.0  12930:45 rpm
 7828 root      20   0 70648 3168 2516 R 19.2  0.0  12870:39 rpm
11104 root      20   0 70648 3160 2512 R 19.2  0.0   1258:59 rpm
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Your question is better suited for one of our sibling sites.  It should get migrated there after there is consensus.

Comment: BTW, see if you can dump `/proc/pid/stack` (for each line in your `top` output, the `pid` is in the leftmost column).  If that doesn't yield anything  useful, check `gstack pid`.

Comment: What are the parents of the processes - `pstree -p`? What are the commandline parameters of the `rpm` processes - `ps -f`?